# Unable to scan number

Tags: r

I want to scan a number from user and want to use that number in switch statement, but I am getting the error that I have mentioned below.

```
a<-scan()
1: switch(a,print(df1),print(df2))
1: 1
```

> Error in scan() : 
>     scan() expected 'a real', got 'switch(a,print(df1),print(df2))'

Comment: Read this tutorial first. You are not using them correctly. http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/scripting.html#switch-statement

Comment: Thanks brother @Masoud

Comment: Also you need to do something like `{a <- scan(); dosomethingwitha();}`, so you won't scan the next command